# Why the flex direction column is working here when is not specified

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this HTML and CSS.When the screen is bigger then 992 px then the flex direction will be row(DEFAULT).But when the screen is smaller then the div's are showed like columns  - with flex direction column.My question is why when i did not specified here that under 992px the flex direction should be column,it is displayed like that ?

```
@media screen and (min-width:992px) {
    .call-outs-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
}
```

```
<div class="call-outs-container">
        <div class="call-out">
          <h4>Feature 1</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam obcaecati vel, placeat numquam omnis sit consectetur nobis molestias! Explicabo deserunt. Consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam obcaecati vel, placeat numquam placeat numquam omnis sit consectetur.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="call-out">
          <h4>Feature 2</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam obcaecati vel, placeat numquam omnis sit consectetur nobis molestias! Explicabo deserunt placeat numquam omnis.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="call-out">
          <h4>Feature 3</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam obcaecati vel, placeat numquam omnis sit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the media query does not apply, you don't have display: flex, to begin with.

So, the display is in columns , but not flex, but block

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer.